# libtorch c++ doesn't release tensor memory

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, pytorch, libtorch

I'm having an issue when using libTorch C++.
I load a module

```
torch::jit::script::Module net = torch::jit::load(universal_path);
```

As this takes some time to load, I store it to use it later on different images that I want to process :

```
    net.to(device);
    net.eval();

    torch::Tensor out_tensor = net.forward({ input_tensor.to(device) }).toTensor().to(cpy);
```

The problem is that the forward function allocates a lot of memory (between 2 to 8MB) but it's not released when out_tensor is going out of scope.

The only way to release the memory is to delete the module as well, but this is not efficient.

Am I missing something?

I'm using libtorch 1.5.1, a bit old, is there known leaks with this version?

Thanks

Comment: One solution after some more research : https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/29893
The env variable solution works, however it reduces speed. Using fixed size sensor should work too, we're trying this solution also.